# Unable to start firefox profile manager on MacOS

Tags: terminal, firefox

I am trying to start the profile manager for Firefox running the following command in a terminal:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin --ProfileManager
```

But this opens just Firefox. Probably a new session, but I'm not sure. It surely does not start the Profile Manager. Is there anything else I can try to start the Profile Manager?

macOS Mojave, Firefox 72.0.2

Comment: Do you already have Firefox running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start the Profile Mnager, Firefox *must not be running*.  Also, the command to start Profile Manager from the command line is:

```
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -ProfileManager
```

Note, that it's only one dash preceding the option and you don't need to use `firefox-bin`.  You can also use the short hand version, `firefox -P` as well.

Mozilla has excellent documentation on its [Command Line Options](https://web.archive.org/web/20210530092017/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#User_Profile).